# Regex - Rename file (move first word to end of string, delete everything before third whitespace)

Tags: regex, powershell

I have multiple files with the same naming convention :

> NAME Invoice N° 2020010001 01_01_2020.pdf

Note that the 'NAME' can be shorter or longer but always attached.

I'd like it to become :

> 2020010001 NAME.pdf

I have to do so in a powershell script which I can do but it's the regex part I'm having trouble with.

My idea would be to store the 'NAME' in a temporary variable then delete everything in the string before the third whitespace, I'd then delete everything after the first whitespace in the resulting string on which I'd finally append 'NAME'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey MDUB88 I made use of the `split` function from powershell. This should do the job:

```
$oldname = "NAME Invoice N° 2020010001 01_01_2020.pdf"
$tmp = $oldname.Split(" ")
$fileextension = $tmp[4].Split(".")[1]
$filename = "$($tmp[3]) $($tmp[0]).$fileextension"
```

Please test it, let me know if it worked and if it did, please mark my post as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

How about using `-replace` with regex groupings, something like this:

```
'NAME Invoice N° 2020010001 01_01_2020.pdf' -replace '^(\w+) Inv.+ (\d+) (\d\d_\d\d_\d{4})(\.pdf)', '$3 $1$4'
```

Comment: Good one! Didn't think about doing it with regex. But this won't work if the file extension is ".docx" or so. Idk if he has only pdf files ;)

Comment: @Nicicalu true but easy to fix  by changing the end group to something like `(\.\w+$)`

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, here's the final script :

```
$directory = (Get-Item -Path ".\").FullName
Get-ChildItem -Path $directory -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination $directory
Get-ChildItem -Path $directory -Recurse -Directory | Remove-Item
foreach($file in get-childitem -Filter *.pdf -r) {
    $oldname = "$file"
    $tmp = $oldname.Split(" ")
    $fileextension = $tmp[4].Split(".")[1]
    $filename = "$($tmp[3]) $($tmp[0]).$fileextension"
    $finalfilename = $filename.Insert(6,'_')
    Rename-Item $file -newname $finalfilename
}
```

It actually adds an underscore after the 6th character of the final name, which wasn't part of the original question. Here's the line that does it :

```
    $finalfilename = $filename.Insert(6,'_')
```